# Calculate new variance when sample size increases

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Suppose I have 10,000 data points with the following statistics:

Sample mean: 7

Sample variance: 4.2 (and hence standard deviation 2.05)

Population mean is also 7.

**Now if I increase the sample size to 12,000 (1.2 times larger), how do I estimate the new variance (if that possible)?**

I think the variance will also be 1.2 times smaller, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is no reason to expect it to change.  Both with $10000$ and $12000$, it is likely to be a good estimate of the population variance.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I thought as you increase the sample size, variance will get smaller as you get closer to the population distribution? 10k and 12k are just sample values. What I'm after is a method to estimate new variance as sample size increases.

Comment: The variance of $\bar{X}$ does go down by a factor of $1.2$. That is probably what you are thinking of.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in the standard deviation, not the standard error (that is, the distribution of X, rather than the distribution of its mean). But thanks.